# CMake custom targets with .Net SDK projects fail on certain machines

Tags: c#, cmake

I'm having a very confusing problem regarding .Net SDK projects in CMake 3.23.2. For a certain C# project that we have, we need to copy dependencies into the binary directory of the application. This is achieved using `add_custom_target()`, as we have had issues in the past where `add_custom_command()` is reported as not yet being compatible with .Net SDK projects.

```
# Create a target which, when "built", simply copies a DLL to the correct directory.
add_custom_target(CopyDependentLibrary
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
  "$<TARGET_FILE:MyDependentLibrary>"
  "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:MyApplication>"
)

# Make the application target depend on this custom target,
# since the application should not be built until after the DLL.
add_dependencies(MyApplication CopyDependentLibrary)
```

CMake accepts this perfectly fine on my and my colleague's machines (both running Windows), and the project builds as it should. However, on our Windows CI machine, which also reports version 3.23.2 of CMake the same as our machines do, configuration throws up an `add_custom_command()` error. This confuses me as we are specifically avoiding the use of `add_custom_command()` for exactly this reason.

```
CMake Error in MyApplication/CMakeLists.txt:
  The target "MyApplication" does not currently support
  add_custom_command as the Visual Studio generators have not yet learned how
  to generate custom commands in .Net SDK-style projects.
```

I have two immediate questions regarding this:

1. Why is `add_custom_command()` involved at all here? Is CMake using it under the hood to execute the `copy` command?
2. Why is the configuration output different across both of these machines, even though they report identical CMake versions?

In case it's helpful, these are the stats reported by the CMake configuration process:

- CMake version is 3.23.2 on developer and CI machines.
- Target Windows version is 10.0.19044 on developer machines, 10.0.17763 on CI machine.
- Compiler version is 19.29.30147.0 on developer machines, 19.29.30146.0 on CI machine.
- The CI machine uses vcpkg, so relies on the toolchain file provided there. Maybe this is suspect? I didn't think it could affect supported CMake functionality, though.

Comment: What is the environmental variable CMAKE_COMMAND set to ? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_COMMAND.html?force_isolation=true

Comment: It should just be the CMake executable as per the CMake docs for this variable. I haven't changed it but can double check.

Comment: The CMAKE_COMMAND variable is simply C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe

Comment: The link shows the cmake without the exe extension.  There may be a bat file for cmake in the folder which should be used.

Comment: I'm not convinced this is the issue - the example CMake path referred to in the doc looks like the Linux executable, and this would be a perfectly valid substitute path for CMake to use on Windows. This variable is managed entirely by CMake itself, and is the same on both my machine and CI. The point is rather that this command is never even run, because the configure step does not complete.

Comment: Is make failing on only linux machines?  Could the linux executable be compiled for a MAC and not Windows?  Did you check the Log files for detailed errors.  A couple of years ago I took a make that worked on windows and got it to run on a Raspberry.  I ended up having to modify the Make to work on linux.  The issue turned out the linux version wanted the path to be where the executables were located while the windows version would work from the parent folder.

Comment: Linux is not a factor in this. All machines are running Windows, including CI.

Comment: Why did you say "looks like the Linux executable"?  Is the make and compiler executable exactly the same on all machines (check byte size).

Comment: I meant that the example path in the documentation looks like the path to the CMake executable as would be present on Linux (`/usr/local/bin/cmake`). As I'm only building on Windows, this is not relevant to me. The path `C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe` is what my script reports, which looks like the appropriate path to CMake for a Windows machine. Regardless, `CMAKE_COMMAND` is executed in the build step, whereas my issue is occuring in the configuration step, so I still don't think it's relevant.

Comment: Did you find the log files?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the reason was that the environment variable `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` was set to the path of vcpkg. Running CMake configure with `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=` solved the problem for me.

By running cmake from the command line with `--trace` (very verbose) you should be able to identify where the custom command is coming from.